# How to find variadic macro implementation in file system

Tags: gcc, macros

I have encounter this macro: `__VA_ARGS__` - variadic macro in a document. It is used to expand the triple dots in macro definition (like `define SMF(...) fprintf(stdout, __VA_ARGS__)`, but when I wanted to find its implementation (How does it expand all agruments given - just its implementation) - I have tried 
`sudo cd /; grep -r '#define __VA_ARGS__` (mentioned `#define`, so it doesnt emit that macro just in 'use' but rather its definition). It was searching quit long, but it only gave I hadnt have permission on some directories (e. g. `sys/kernel/debug/block/loop17/hctx0/cpu3/read_rq_list` - even when trigered with sudo - dont know why, but thats another story). Still didnt tell where to look (in what file). So if it didnt find that macro from root dir (and recursively look in others), where should I look then?

PS: I know that when macro starts with double underscore, it is either system macro or compilator (gcc) macro, but when I did similar with gcc (grep `__VA_ARGS__` via `man gcc | grep ...`), even there no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic macros are part of the C11 language specification (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), and of the [GNU `cpp` preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

They are implemented inside the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler itself. Beware, that compiler is very complex. Read about [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/) and glance into the **source code** of the GCC compiler since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). Look inside the [`libcpp/` directory](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libcpp/) of recent GCC source code.

Of course, you then want to [download the source code of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) (not just the executables).

Then, look into the [GCC resource center](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/) (by several Indian academics) to start understanding GCC. This will require an important effort (at least several months, and probably several years) from your part, since GCC has dozen of millions of source code lines. But trying to understand the organization of GCC is an exciting adventure. You may want to ask *focused* questions on one of the [GCC mailing lists](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html).

I wrote several years ago (within the obsolete [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project) many slides about GCC internals. The details are obsolete. But most ideas are still relevant, and I guess that some figures could still help you to understand GCC. More recently, my [Bismon draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) gives some explanations (related to recent versions of GCC).

You could be interested in playing with (and writing your own) [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

Comment: But where can I find the file with the implementaion? I dont know how to search in gcc (because I dont even know of how many exe files is gcc built of, so how can I?)

Comment: Download the source code of GCC, and look inside it. You may need months of efforts (GCC has about twenty millions of source lines) to understand GCC. I spent 8 years full time on trying to understand some front-end and some parts of the middle-end. Maybe you are more clever and could need just a few years.

Comment: btw, why I had not have permission, when triggeres command with sudo?

Comment: The real question is how much efforts can you spend in understanding GCC internals. In my opinion and past experience, you need to budget at least one full-time year of work

Comment: That doesnt matter, I can consider it as part of my educational way, no matter of the cost. I would needed no matter what later on, so why not start right now?

Comment: Then I gave you several valuable links. Welcome inside the GCC community. Start by compiling GCC from its source code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204260/discussion-between-herdsman-and-basile-starynkevitch).